# how to create a makefile linux

Tags: c, makefile, autoconf, automake

I have the following: a .c code, a .h code plus a .o file and a -lib... library. When I compile the c code with gcc I do:

```
gcc code.c -o code file.o -library
```

How to create a makefile?

I currently have with autoconf and automake?

I currently have:

```
Makefile

all: 
  gcc code.c -o code file.o -library

clean:

 rm -f code
```

When I compile make I get:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Need some help. Thx

Comment: Does `file.o` have a corresponding `file.c`?

Comment: yes it does. It also have a file.h

Comment: say ".PHONY: all" on a separate line before "all" in the makefile (see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html), same for "clean". Also, you do not specify that "all" depends on anything, whereas in should depend on "code", "code" should depend on "code.c" and "file.o", "file.o" should depend on file.c etc.

Comment: Just google for Makefile tutorials... lot of stuffs avail.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry I have to give this answer, but have you tried https://www.google.com/search?q=makefile+tutorial?

Pick one, and learn how to create a Makefile. You don't need the autotools.

It took me 5 minutes to come up with this, by reading [Makefile Tutorial](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/):

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
CLIBS=-lX11
OUT=code
OBJS=code.o file.o


$(OUT): code.o file.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CLIBS) -o $(OUT) $(OBJS)
code.o: code.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c code.c -o code.o
file.o: file.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c file.c -o file.o

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(OUT)
```

> If on the computer the -library doesn t exist I want to install it automatically.

This is specific to the distribution used and you need root access on the machine. Doing it like this is not how it's done. Instead, you should create a package specific for your distribution where you specify the dependencies.

For instance, for Ubuntu (since it's the most used distribution), you'd create a .deb file: http://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging

This, however, has nothing to do with your initial question.

Comment: thx for your answer. Could you please still help me? I want to also include the dependencies. If on the computer the -library doesn t exist I want to install it automatically.

Comment: You need to write rules to install the library seperately.
But you will need admin rights to do that. Can you describe more what you are trying to do? Are you trying to make a package which should be distributed ?

Comment: no. I just want to create a makefile with automake and autoconf

Comment: You don't need automake and autoconf for this simple task.

Comment: In case you must have the autotools, then you can read the [Autotools tutorial](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html)

Comment: @Flaxius can you please tell me what is -Wall and how to automatic install that CLIBS=-lx11? -lX11 is -library (the library that I have) ? Also after this makefile I can now create a config.in in order to have the posibiliti to make and makeinstall? Also -library is a library that needs to be installed if it is not on the computer. How to do that?

Comment: @justAngela please see my updated answer. CLIBS should be edited to contain the actual libraries. `-Wall` means "warn all", a gcc flag you can read about by typing in the console `man gcc`.

Comment: and how to include the installation  with sudo apt get install the library in case it is not installed?

Comment: @justAngela that is subject to another question, which doesn't belong on SO, but on http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/. It's not the area of programming any more, once you have the `.deb`.

Comment: i see. I want to ask you one more thing. If the file.o has a file.lo can I put it in the makefile instead of the .c and file.h? WHY? Because i have come compilation errors. The file.c also expects some other headers which i don t have. thx

Comment: file.{c,h} are source codes, file.o is an object file, and they're not interchargeable. "some compilation errors" is ambiguos, you have to open a new question and post the concrete errors and ask for help about that. "file.c expects some other headers" can be fixed by using the `-I` in CFLAGS **with the appropiate directory**, once you locate the directory where the headers are located. Your issues however go far beyond the scope of your question "*how to create a makefile linux*".

Comment: thx. one more thing? If i have a ifdef in the .c code how to include it in the makefike? -DVALUE=1 for example. How to include this in the makefile?

Comment: how to use AUTOMAKE AND AUTOCONF FOR THIS CODE I HAVE?

Comment: If you do not understand how to write a simple Makefile, you do not want to even contemplate using automake and autoconf.  You've got a *lot* of learning to do before you should attempt to use those tools.

Answer (score 2):

See this code this may help you.

For example create a C test file "test.c" and then create makefile as shown below.

**Makefile**

```
 all:

        cc -o test test.c

 clean:

        rm -f test
```

Save this file as "Makefile"

1. Run this makefile by `make` command. It then creates test executable file at present directory
2. Run the file using `./test`
3. You can use `make clean` to delete the executable file(test).

For any reference to see [Makefile tutorial](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html)

Comment: This does not add much to what is already present in the original question, or the accepted answer.